# Is it safe to use async with external js files?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asynchronous, cdn

From what I've read, using "async" in references to external js files, such as:

```
<script scr="http://someCDN/bla.js" async />
```

might provide the best performance. However, there also seems to be a potential issue with scripts thus referenced executing in any which order. But for jQuery and jQueryUI (or any jQuery-based js file), you need jQuery to load first, and only thereafter jQueryUI (or fancybox, or goMap, or whatever the case is).

So: Is async a tease, or can it be safely used in such situations (referencing jQuery and its spawn hosted on CDNs)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`async`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async) safely with *unrelated* scripts. But if you need to load them in order (such as your example), you can't just put `async` on both of them and hope for the best — you'll be creating a race condition.

I found [this article](http://www.jspatterns.com/the-ridiculous-case-of-adding-a-script-element/) on various ways to load scripts quite useful, FWIW.

Comment: So it sounds like that since every jQuery library relies on jQuery itself, async is simply a pipe dream.

Comment: @ClayShannon: Only if you load them separately. It's quite common to take jQuery and all of your plugins (including jQuery UI), combine and minify them, and deliver them as a single file.

Comment: So that would preclude going the CDN route, or is there a way to do that...probably not, as the jQueryUI is developer-specific (depending on what you selected for your download) - unless you take the whole jQueryUI shebang...

Comment: @ClayShannon: Well, you can use a CDN, you just can't use one of the pre-loaded free ones. The benefit of that varies. If you *just* need jQuery, it's a no-brainer (in my view): Load it from the CDN. If you're also loading a couple of plug-ins, the returns fall right away. Now of course, you could load jQuery *blocking* from a public free CDN, and then load your combined plug-ins async from your own server... Note - I added a link to the answer that my be useful. (Or not.)

Comment: So what about "defer" - is that only helpful as a way of "virtually" moving script references from the start of the (html) body to the end of the body?

Comment: @ClayShannon: Sadly, [not if you need to support IE9 and earlier](https://github.com/h5bp/lazyweb-requests/issues/42). Although Microsoft innovated `defer`, there's a bug in the implementation that's only fixed in IE10. AFAIK, the only way to get async, ordered script loading is to use a script loader (`RequireJS` or similar). A minimal one can be written in about 15 lines of code (using `onload`/`onerror` [`onreadystate` on older IE]).